# summing value of row yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a table where i store the userId, and points. Everytime a user uses a transaction, they will be awarded points and these points are stored in UserPoints. It will post new rows for each transaction.

id    |    userId      | points

1            2             38

2            18            50

3            2             12

4            10            13

5            15            15

like the table above, userID 2 has multiple lines, i want to add all the value that userId 2 have. i want to put the calculation inside the model MUserTotal inside the variable totalPointsValue().

Here is what i have so far

```
public function totalPointsValue() {

    user = $this->userId;

}
```

Comment: create group by on userId where user_id is $this->userID query using CDbCriteria and select sum(points). assign the variable.. All Done...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [statical query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query).

Basically you create a relation ship on the user Class to the UserPoints of type STAT, and specify the criteria:

```
<?php
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'points'=>array(
                self::STAT, // Declare this relation as statical
                'user_points', // The table where you are storing the points
                'userId', // The foreign key on that table
                'select' => "SUM(points)", // make it SUM instead of default COUNT
                'group' => "userId" // Group by this field when adding points
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

After that you can use the relationship as you would use any other:

```
<?php
$user = User::model()->findbyPk(1);
echo $user->points;
```

Comment: That will definitely work. Just want to point out though, that these types of values are calculated on the fly, and require additional SQL queries. If you need to do any SQL operations on the results (sort by, MIN() MAX(), etc) you will either need to create a view table or use triggers to update a user table field.

Comment: i've never heard of Statistical Query before, will do some reading on it. thanks @Asgaroth

Answer (score 0):

or if you need to create the model MUserTotal ... just create a view that contains the userId and sum of his points, and create the model for this view ... the query will be some thing like 
    select user_id, sum(points) from user_points group by user_id